# Python/Django "if statement" syntax incorrect?

Tags: python, django, if-statement, syntax-error

```
for cart_item in cart_products:
    if **cart_item.**product.id = p.id:
        # update the quantity if found
        cart_item.augment_quantity(quantity)
        product_in_cart = True
if not product_in_cart:  
    # create and save a new cart item
    ci = CartItem()
    ci.product = p
    ci.quantity = quantity
    ci.cart_id = _cart_id(request)
    ci.save()
```

I've just put together my shopping cart and this is the simple logic that checks to make sure the item isn't already in someones cart, in case they try to add it again by mistake.  The error crops up in the bolded section...a `:` is expected instead of a `.`  The server throws an error AND eclipse is catching the syntax error.

Why is the dot syntax breaking the if statement?  If more context is needed, let me know, but I am guessing I am just not understanding the syntax requirements of the if statement properly.

Comment: What is the exact text of the error you receive?

Comment: Looks like you need `==` equality instead of `=` assignment here: `if cart_item.product.id = p.id:`

Comment: `SyntaxError at /
invalid syntax (cart.py, line 42)`  Obviously, the line `if **cart_item.**product.id = p.id:` is line 42

Comment: Yup, I knew I was being a dingus somehow, it was indeed equality assignment.  I'm not totally familiar with stackoverflow procedure...should you write that as an answer so I can accept it, or should I close the question down?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The comparison operator in Python is `==`, not `=`.